# Plants Not Growing Food

Tags: fallout-76

In Fallout 76 I've planted mutfruit, blackberry, corn, and tato plants, but they sit there and never actually make any food to harvest. I've tried planting them in my own CAMP, my friend's CAMP, even workshops claimed by me.

Instructions I've seen online essentially just say "plant the crops." Nothing I've found online seems to indicate this is bugged. Though I've not played Fallout 4, I've searched through the questions for that but didn't see anything related that might help.

Other resource production stations like water purifiers and mineral extractors produce results as expected. With a production rate of 17/hr for the crops, I'd expect something to be available approximately every four minutes. I've waited over an hour in one of my workshops with no results. I even made sure nobody came through and harvested them, so I know for sure nothing was produced.

Is there anything required for growing plants like water or fertilizer?

How do you get the crops to actually grow food?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo76/comments/9xclnz/do_i_really_need_plans_to_grow_crops_where_are/), you need fertilizer when planting crops.

[This thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo76/comments/9tdfpd/crops_not_growing/) also suggests the crops may be damaged and you should check if they need repairs.

It looks like [other people](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo76/comments/9wy603/why_wont_my_crops_produce_food/) have reported that the prompt to harvest is invisible and that the plant does not appear to be ripe. However, they are still able to harvest from these plants by interacting with them.

It doesn't hurt to relocate your camp and/or relog after trying these since that can occasionally shake something loose.